# Handle the Role paramater of the Authorize tag in the AuthenticationHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

So I'm trying to create a custom authorisation system which supports my custom token in my ASP.NET core web API. I know how to create custom handlers and all but I don't know one thing, I even don't know if it's even possible, how can I read the Role attribute from:

```
[Authorize(Roles="role")]
```

this is my custom authorisation handler:

```
public class Auth : AuthenticationHandler<AuthOptions>
{
    //private static Models.flowerpowerContext context = new Models.flowerpowerContext
    private Token.AuthToken authToken;
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private Models.flowerpowerContext _context;

    public Auth(IOptionsMonitor<AuthOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        DbContextOptions<Models.flowerpowerContext> _options = new DbContextOptions<Models.flowerpowerContext>();
        _context = new Models.flowerpowerContext(_options);
        string test = options.ToString();



        authToken = new Token.AuthToken(_context);
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        Models.Token _token = new Models.Token();
        Token.Hasher hasher = new Token.Hasher();

        var bearer = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        string token = bearer.ToString();



        _token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Token>(hasher.DecodeHash(token));

        string id = "";

        return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
    }
}
```

The above handler works fine and it get's the token from the Authorization header. And the AuthOptions only have an empty constructor.

I couldn't find anything that would seem, at least to me, to retrieve the value of the Roles parameter. Does anybody know a better approach/work-around or a direct solution to this, and also if this is even possible?

**EDIT:**
Forgot to mention why I want to do this; I want to do this because the role of the user has been defined within my custom token. And I need to compare it to the required role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after I followed CodeFuller's responses I came up with a solution.
I basically I had to create a Claim collection like this:

```
IList<Claim> claimCollection = new List<Claim>
{
     new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, _token.TokenEmail),
     new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, _token.TokenRole)
};
```

Then I had to appoint a ClaimsIdentity and a ClaimsPrinciple. After this I had to create an AuthenticationTicket like this:

```
AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, "Custom scheme");
```

And all I had to do now was to return this:

```
return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
```

This allowed me to verify roles from my custom token. This basically allowed me to do this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

To get some more explanation about this matter you should check out CodeFuller's response.

Answer (score 3):

You mix up two concepts here, authentication and authorization.

Authentication is the process of verifying who the user is.

Authorization is the process of verifying that the user has the access to requested resource.

Your `Auth` class is responsible for authentication, not authorization. If request is successfully authenticated, `HandleAuthenticateAsync` method should return instance of `AuthenticateResult` with filled `Principal` property of `ClaimsPrincipal` type.  `ClaimsPrincipal` implements `IPrincipal` interface that has method `bool IsInRole(string role)`.

Thus after the authentication step, it's known for the principal associated with the request, whether hi is in specific role. And the list of roles authorized for specific controller or action is specified in `Roles` property of `AuthorizeAttribute`. In your example if request principal is in "role", request will be successfully authorized. If he is not, request will fail with 401 or 403 error. This code of checking principal role is already implemented in `AuthorizeAttribute` filter. You don't need to reinvent it until you implement your custom authorization filter (I remind you that your `Auth` class is an authentication filter).

So answering your question about handling the user role: you should just return proper principal object that returns correct value for `IsInRole(string role)` method. All the rest will be handled by default authorization filter.

Comment: So I have to return AuthenticateResult.Succeed(ticket) and then check if the user has the required role? Also do you want to provide a small example?

Comment: "So I have to return AuthenticateResult.Succeed(ticket)" - Yes, correctly. "and then check if the user has the required role" - This check will be made by `AuthorizeAttribute`, you don't have to perform this check. Just make sure you correctly setup the role for the principal you return. [Here is example](https://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/writing-an-authenticationhandler-for-katana) of `AuthenticationHandler` implementation.

Comment: Can you also please tell me how to fill the ticket, I'm quite new to this.

Comment: It really depends on authentication provider you're going to use. Check this set of articles: https://dotnetcodr.com/2013/02/11/introduction-to-claims-based-security-in-net4-5-with-c-part-1/ It explains claims based security in detail.